# Automatically create files based on expanding snippets?

Tags: filetype-html, plugin-ultisnips, filetype-scss

when developing for web (in Vim) I'm always using the [BEM](http://getbem.com) methodology. I have identified that I always go through the same steps when adding a new block element, and I'm looking for ways to automate the whole/or parts of the process.

What I now have to do for each block being added:

Using UltiSnips, `c-` is expanded and edited into something like this:

```
<!-- Component: Button -->
<div class="c-button">
  <div class="c-button__border">
    <img class="c-button__icon" src="img/mic-off.svg" />
  </div> 
  <p class="c-button__title">Mic off</p>  
</div>
```

Then I have to navigate to `src/sass/components/` and add a file named `_c-button.sass` with the content:

```
.c-button

  &__border
  &__icon
  &__title
```

Finally edit `src/sass/main.sass` and add `@import 'components/button'` to the end of the file.

So any tips/ideas how to start to automate this process further?

Comment: I think it's not Vim's job to create file and put skeleton in them (Vim is a text editor). You might be looking for a tool like [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) which allows you to scafold a project but also to automate the addition of new components in web project (and basically in any project with the right generator)